# Concurrency and Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, process

I'm not very experienced with subjects such as Concurrency and Multithreading. In fact, in most of my web-development career I had never needed to touch these subjects.

I feel like it's an important concept, especially for Desktop applications and basically any other application that doesn't generate HTML :).

After reading a bit on concurrency, it seems to be better supported in languages like Go (google programming language) and I don't quite understand why would a language be better than others at a concept like *concurrency*, since it's basically about being able to fork() processes and compute stuff in parallel, right? Isn't this how programming works?

Multithreading seems to be a branch of concurrency as it allows you to run things in parallel beneath the same process, although it seems to be platform specific how it's implemented.

I guess my question is, **why would specific languages be better at *concurrency* than others and why would fork()ing processes be a better solution rather than just using threads?**

Comment: nitpick - Go isn't "Google's programming lanuage" .  It is a language that some of their employees invented, but last I heard, it is not used by Google internally yet.

Comment: It says "google programming language", but in any case I don't see anything wrong with referring to a language developed and promoted by Google as "Google's".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well for one thing, multiple threads are not the same as multiple processes, so fork() really does not apply here.

Multithreading/parallel processing is *hard*.  First you have to figure out how to actually partition the task to be done.  Then you have to coordinate all of the parallel bits, which may need to talk to each other or share resources.  Then you need to consolidate the results, which in some cases can be every bit as difficult as the previous two steps.  I'm simplifying here, but hopefully you get the idea.

So your question is, why would some languages be better at it?  Well, several things can make it easier:

- Optimized immutable data structures.  You want to stick to immutable structures whenever possible in parallel processing, because they are much easier to reason about.  Some languages have better support for these, and some have various optimizations, i.e. the ability to splice collections together without any actual copying while still enforcing the immutability.  You can always build your own structures like these, but it's easier if the language or framework does it for you.
- Synchronization primitives and ease of using them.  When different threads do share state, they need to be synchronized and there are many different ways to accomplish this.  The wider the array of sync primitives you get, the easier your task will ultimately be.  Performance will take a hit if you have to sync with a critical section instead of a reader-writer lock.
- Atomic transactions.  Even better than a wide array of sync primitives is not having to use them at all.  Database engines are very good at this; instead of you, the programmer, having to figure out exactly which resources you need to lock and when and how, you just say to the compiler or interpreter, "all of the stuff below this line needs to happen together, so make sure nobody else messes around with it while I'm using it."  And the engine will figure out the locking for you.  You almost never get this kind of simplicity in an abstract programming language, but the closer you can come, the better.  Thread-safe objects that combine multiple common operations into one are a start.
- Automatic parallelism.  Let's say you have to iterate through a long list of items and transform them somehow, like multiply 50,000 10x10 matrices.  Wouldn't it be nice if you could just tell the compiler: *Hey, each operation can be done independently, so use a separate CPU core for each one?*  Without having to actually implement the threading yourself?  Some languages support this kind of thing; for example, the .NET team has been working on PLINQ.

Those are just a few examples of things that can make your life easier in parallel/multi-threaded applications.  I'm sure that there are many more.

Comment: +1. Side-effect free languages also make things easier (such functional ones, like Haskell).

Answer (score 4):

In languages that are not designed for concurrency, you must rely upon low-level system calls and manage a lot of things yourself. In contrast, a programming language designed for concurrency, like Erlang, will provide high-level constructs that hide the low-level details. This makes it easier to reason about the correctness of your code, and also results in more portable code.

Also, in a programming language designed for concurrency, there are typically only a handful of ways to do concurrent things, which leads to consistency.  In contrast, if the programming language was not designed for concurrency, then different libraries and different programmers will do things in different ways, making it difficult to make choices about how to do them.

It's a bit like the difference between a programming language with automated garbage collection and one without.  Without the automation, the programmer has to think a lot about implementation details.

The difference between multithreaded programming and multi-process programming (i.e., fork()), is that a multithreaded program may be more efficient because data doesn't have to be passed across process boundaries, but a multi-process approach may be more robust.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your question of why `fork()` instead of threading: when you use separate processes, you get automatic separation of address spaces. In multithreaded programs, it is very common for threads to communicate using their (naturally) shared memory. This is very efficient, but it is also hard to get all the synchronization between threads right, and this is why some languages are better at multithreading than others: they provide better abstractions to handle the common cases of communication between threads.

With separate processes, you don't have these problems to the same extent. Typically, you set up communication between processes to follow some form of message-passing pattern, which is easier to get right. (Well, you can use shared memory between processes too, but that's not as common as message passing.) On Unix systems `fork()` has typically been very cheap, so traditional design of concurrent programs in Unix uses processes, and pipes to communicate between them, but on systems where process creation is an expensive operation, threads are often regarded as the better approach.

Answer (score 2):

I'm studying the subject (right now :D) and one of the things that seems a very important difference on concurrency between languages is the language expressive power on concurrency.

For example C++ has no native support to concurrency and it rely on functions provided by the OS.

Java is a step above because has some built-in methods while others are left to the OS (threads scheduling or priority for example).

**Instead** one of what seems to be one of the best programming languages supporting concurrency is Ada which has in fact a **whole concurrency-model built in** (scheduling and priority included).

Why is this important? Because of the **portability**!

Using a language with good concurrency expressive power allows you to bring your concurrent program to Windows, linux or Mac withouth great fears about the way it will work.
For example: thread priority will be applied in the **same way** in your Ada program running in windows, linux or Mac while it can be **really different** (ignored in some OS and applied in others) with Java or C++.

This is what seem to me by the course I'm taking at the university right now :)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by native support. It looks like the C++ standard does have support for threads http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218786/concurrent-programming-c

Comment: Support for threads was added to C++ in the C++11 standard, which was accepted after this answer was written.

Answer (score 1):

Re:  why some languages are better for concurrency than others:  it all depends on the tools that the language offers to the programmer.  Some languages, like C++, give you low-level access to the system threads.  Java has all kinds of libraries that offer constructs for concurrent programming, kind of like design patterns (see latch, barrier, et al).  Some languages make it easier than others to deal with threads.  Some languages keep you from sharing state between threads, which is a major source of bugs.

And then some languages have different underlying thread models than others.  Python's thread model, as I understand it, uses a single system thread and handles all the context-switching itself, which is not as clean as it is only as granular as a single Python instruction.

As an analogy, it's like asking why some languages are better at handling regular expressions, or searching, or doing complex math when in the end its all just moving bits around.

Edit:  frunsi is correct, Python threads are system threads (apparently this is a common misconception).  The problem I was referring to was with the GIL, or global interpreter lock, which controls thread execution.  Only a single thread can run in the Python interpreter at once, and context is only switched between instructions.  My knowledge of Python multithreading mainly comes from this paper:  [www.dabeaz.com/python/GIL.pdf](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/GIL.pdf) .  Maybe a little off topic, but a good reference nonetheless.

Comment: The comment on python is wrong, maybe you were thinking of some kind of lightweight threads? They have a different intent. See http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html#module-thread. Though there is (or was) a problem with a global interpreter lock in python, but your statement is plainly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**To fork is human to thread is divine :D**

Forking involves the kernel and creates a seperate adress space -- meaning proc X and Y can't easily share and need to use IPC primitives, and creating a thread allows in process synchronization which is FAR faster than IPC which involves kernel context switches by both processes and needless thread yield's (which involve the kernel to wake said thread up).

However there is a multitude of reasons why different concurrency models are better than others. I'm just giving you the rough rule of thumb for general programming. For example not forking might endanger logic which could be separated out by forking (I love that word) -- endangered because if the other logic in the process crashes it , well said logic is going down with the process.

Answer (score 0):

no language is better than an other one, it's all about the concepts. Doing things simultaniously by processes consumes usually more resources than threads (wich could be seen as lightweight processes) some languages come with easy too use libs.
Java threads are easy too use, Posix threads (C on unix) are a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency is basically being able to fork() processes and compute stuff in parallel the same way memory management is basically being able to call malloc.  It is part of the story, but not all of it.  Being able to simplify the issues relating to concurrency is the difference between languages that are good at concurrency and those that just can be concurrent.

Comment: No. Concurrency is not parallel.

Answer (score 0):

The language choice depends on the application you want to do.

Do you want to create a highly scalable system, with lots of incoming "requests"? Then Erlang may be a good choice. It is known to be a good fit for "highly concurrent" application scenarios.

If you want to write a typical game and want it to use the now typically available dual or quad core CPUs of your audience, then you are bound to different decisions (frameworks, engines, libraries, available hardware interfaces). In this case, you will use threads, and thread pools to offload processing work. Most probably you will use a kind of message queue to communicate between the threads.

In (server-side) web-development you most probably already gained some experience in concurrent programming! Maybe you were not aware of it, because the language and the given framework (maybe Apache & PHP) provided you with an environment that took the burden off your shoulders.